# Stream Audio from PC to Phone(Android) using SCO over Bluetooth

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

**On my Phone:**

```
// Configure Audio:
BluetoothAudio = (AudioManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
BluetoothAudio.Mode = Mode.InCall;
BluetoothAudio.BluetoothScoOn = true;
BluetoothAudio.StartBluetoothSco();
```

**On my PC:**

```
public byte[] AudioByteData
{
get;
set;
}

public int StreamStartPosition
{
get;
set;
}

public int StreamEndPosition
{
get;
set;
}

public StreamAudio(byte[] AudioData)
{
this.AudioByteData = AudioData;

AudioTimer.Elapsed += AudioTimer_Elapsed;
AudioTimer.Interval = 20;
AudioTimer.Enabled = true;
AudioTimer.Start();
}

private void AudioTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

According to the documentation I have read, this article: [Creating audio applications with Bluetooth](http://www.design-reuse.com/articles/5360/creating-audio-applications-with-bluetooth.html) as an example, sending Byte Chunks over a period of time, is the way to 'stream' if you like Audio over Bluetooth:

> In an MP3 application, suppose the device is sending an MP3 stream from a file encoded at 128 kbit/sec and 48 kHz sample frequency. This means an MP3 audio frame 384 bytes long is sent every 24.0 msec. So, if the device simply sets a periodic timer for 24.0 msec and sends a packet when the timer expires the constant bit rate will be maintained.

My question is, is there a better way than this?

Comment: Define better, that's subjective. First of all, what is your doubt/problem with the way that has been suggested in your quote?

Comment: @SimonBosley - Article Date: 4/18/2003 - Thats 7.2 Moore's Law Epocs. Evolution tells me there should be a better way to do it by now. How accurate is the average System Timer? The Article does say there are problems with this method. The Article from Jason Hillyard, Senior Software Engineer, Widcomm, Inc. is excellent, but it is outdated, Shame its all I can really find...

Comment: Moore's law only states that there will be faster hardware on which run it it - "Moore's law (/mɔərz.ˈlɔː/) is the observation that the number of transistors in a dense integrated circuit doubles approximately every two years." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law. What if the method is already perfected? Keep on searching though... it does seem a little dated :-)